# Shallow Copy (each item by referece)

Tags: python-3.x, reference

In the following code:

```
l1 = [3, [66, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
l2 = list(l1)
l1.append(100)
l1[1].remove(55)
l1[0] = 5
print('l1:', l1)
print('l2:', l2)
l2[1] += [33, 22]
l2[2] += (10, 11)
print('l1:', l1)
print('l2:', l2)
```

([Pythontour link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=l1%20%3D%20%5B3,%20%5B66,%2055,%2044%5D,%20%287,%208,%209%29%5D%0Al2%20%3D%20list%28l1%29%0Al1.append%28100%29%0Al1%5B1%5D.remove%2855%29%0Al1%5B0%5D%20%3D%205%0Aprint%28'l1%3A',%20l1%29%0Aprint%28'l2%3A',%20l2%29%0Al2%5B1%5D%20%2B%3D%20%5B33,%2022%5D%0Al2%5B2%5D%20%2B%3D%20%2810,%2011%29%0Aprint%28'l1%3A',%20l1%29%0Aprint%28'l2%3A',%20l2%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=2&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false))

When we create a shallow copy of the list, for example:

```
l1 = [3, [66, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
l2 = list(l1)
```

Should't `l2` be filled with references to he same items held by the original container? Why not like the tuple and list inside, the 3 is not referenced to the original list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The references are not to the original container. Rather, both containers have  references to the same objects. This shows that both `l1` and `l2` contain references to the same objects:

```
>>> l1=[3, [66, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
>>> l2 = list(l1)
>>> id(l1[0])==id(l2[0])
True
>>> id(l1[1])==id(l2[1])
True
```

The difference is that integers are not mutable objects, and lists are. So if you change `l1[1][0]` (in other words `66`), this will happen:

```
>>> l1[1][0]
66
>>> l1[1][0] += 1
>>> l1
[3, [67, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
>>> l2
[3, [67, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
```

But if you do that to the first element of `l1`, the same thing doesn't happen:

```
>>> l1[0] += 1
l1
>>> [4, [67, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
l2
>>> [3, [67, 55, 44], (7, 8, 9)]
```

*This is what you want.* `l1[0]` originally referred to the integer 3 in a constant pool. If you changed the meaning of that reference, that would change the meaning of the literal `3` everywhere in your program (was 3, is now 4).

It was actually possible to do that in Fortran IV, but that was widely agreed to be a bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed explanation! it is crystal clear now to me! I just have one more questions about mutable and not mutable objects.  for example like list, it is mutable because essentially it is linked list? so that the head point to the start of the list and will never change if you add or change of element of the list? But tuples are just a data structure that contains the immutable references of each elements?               Just want to know the essence of mutable and immutable , and why it is .     Thank you!

Comment: Mutability/immutability is by design and has nothing to do with implementation. Python compiles the source code constant `3` to a reference for efficiency: not because one would want to change the contents of the reference. Python string variables are immutable too. That is not because changing the contents of the reference makes no sense (C programmers do it all the time), but again for efficiency. In Erlang *all* variables are immutable, in the same way that Python strings and tuples are. That requires a different (advocates say more reliable) style of programming.

Comment: Thank you BoarGules! Excellent explanations! btw , I do think manipulating memories and passing value or pointers made C very powerful in its way comparing to python :)